# eslint maximum nested parentheses rule

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there any eslint rule that would prevent someone from doing this

`const result = bar(baz());`

I would prefer

`const a = baz();
const result = bar(a);`

Ideally I could configure maximum nesting, so maybe 1 nesting is okay but more than that is not

`foo(bar(baz()))`

Comment: for callbacks only there's https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-nested-callbacks

Comment: @WillCain Yup, already using that one

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any [existing eslint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) or plugin specifically for the case you mention. The closest one I can find is for a subset of the behavior applying only to nested callbacks: [max-nested-callbacks](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-nested-callbacks). You could [write your own plugin](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins).